# Finding the smoothest function bounded by two other functions

Tags: optimization, regularization

Suppose I have two polynomial functions $f(x)$ and $z(x)$ defined over some closed interval $[a,b]$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. The functions are subject only to the restriction that $f(x) > z(x)$ $\forall$ $x$.

I am trying to find a function $g(x)$ that meets the following conditions for any closed interval $[a, b]$ on $x$:

**Condition 1**:  $f(x) > g(x) > z(x)$

This ensures that $g(x)$ never "touches" either function, being bounded above by $f(x)$ and bounded below by $z(x)$

**Condition 2**: Does so with the "shortest" line possible subject to Condition 1.

I'm not sure how to precisely define "shortest" in this context, but if someone walked along the line, the total distance travelled would be the smallest. I think about this in terms of the typical GAM/Penalized Spline penalty on "squiggliness": minimizing something like $(g(x+h) - g(x))^2$ $\forall$ $x \in [a,b]$.

**How would I go about finding $g(x)$?**

#### Substantive Motivation/Application

A substantive motivation for this question occurs in racing athletics: the athlete must travel from the starting line to the finishing subject to staying on the course. The course can be arbitrarily wide or narrow at different points.  Assuming the course is homogenous, the athlete seeks to find the shortest route. While this seems like a Traveling Salesman problem, I'm not sure if the upper and lower bounds make this more tractable or provide a different solution.

Comment: A, I just see that $f$ and $z$ are polynomials, that takes care of the differentiability... the remaining problem is that they are defined over all of $\mathbf{R}$, so the arc length of any $g$ will be infinite in any case, so one would need to be a little more sophisticated about the "minimum length" aspect.

Comment: @Henry: Ah, good point, sorry... I'll start deleting those comments even I see are wrong...

Comment: There are several issues with this question. 1) I think you need to restrict to finite intervals because otherwise lengths may become infinite. 2) The standard definition of "travel distance" is [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length). This is not "squiggliness". 3) A solution will not exist in general. As evidenced by two half circles (f with large and z with small diameter). The shortest path will be equal to z hence violating the ">" restriction. In math lingo your solution space is not closed.

Comment: Even if you fix the ">" issue you will run into problems unless you restrict the curvature (i.e. higher order derivatives). Shortest solutions may be piecewise linear, hence not differentiable. And you will have sequences of ever shorter polynomials converging to those. Again showing that your solution space is not closed.

Comment: Check out the similar problem of the [racing line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racing_line) which is not about the shortest but the fastest path. This is a very different problem from the traveling salesman. This type of problem is called [variational problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Example).

Comment: @gg (1) Perhaps we can define the function on $[a,b]$ instead of $\mathbb(R)$ then. (2) Good point on a solution being possibly piecewise linear, for some reason thought that wouldn't be the case. (3) The racing line problem you linked to is similar - the key difference being I'm looking at a simpler case that assumes a "constant speed."

Comment: Hm, maybe this becomes more tractable if we assume all 3 functions are polynomials of arbitrary degree?